# trying to get different outputs from polymorphic function

Tags: c++, function, class, c++11, polymorphism

Hi StackOverflow community!
I'm expecting different outputs depending on the class of object to be printed but that's not the case.

### Medium.h

```
#include "Datum.h"
#include "Person.h"

class Medium
{
public:
    Medium(std::string initTitel);
    virtual ~Medium(void);
    void ausgabe() const;
    bool ausleihen(Person person, Datum ausleihdatum);
    void zurueckgeben();
    unsigned int getID();
protected:
    static unsigned int currentID;
    unsigned int ID;
    std::string titel;
    bool status;
    Datum datumAusgeliehen;
    Person personAusgeliehen;
};
```

### **Medium.cpp**

```
#include "Medium.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

unsigned int Medium::currentID = 1;

Medium::Medium(std::string initTitel): titel(initTitel), status(false)
{
    ID = currentID++;
}
Medium::~Medium(void)  {}
void Medium::ausgabe() const
{
    std::cout << "ID: " << ID << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Titel: " << titel << std::endl;
    switch (status)
    {
    case true:
        std::cout << "Status : Das Medium ist seit dem " 
                  << datumAusgeliehen  << " an " 
                  << personAusgeliehen.getName() << " ausgeliehen." 
                  << std::endl;
        break;

    case false:
        std::cout << "Status: Medium ist zurzeit nicht verliehen." << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

The function prints **ID**, **title** and **status** to console.
Now depending on the *type* of `Medium`, I would like to print extra information using the function `void ausgabe() const`.

Example: If the Medium is a `book`(*in german buch = book*), information about *author* should be printed, in addition to other information available in `Medium` class. i.e, I have got the *subclass* called `Buch` which also has an `void ausgabe() const` function, which should print this extra information in class `Buch`.

### Buch.h

```
#include "Medium.h"
class Buch: public Medium
{
public:
    Buch();
    Buch(std::string initTitel, std::string initAutor);
    virtual ~Buch();
    void ausgabe() const;
private:
    std::string autor;
};
```

### Buch.cpp

```
#include "Buch.h"
Buch::Buch(std::string initTitel, std::string initAutor): Medium(initTitel), autor(initAutor) 
{ // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  }

Buch::~Buch()    { // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub   }

void Buch::ausgabe() const
{
    Medium::ausgabe();
    std::cout << "Autor: " << autor << std::endl;
}
```

As far as I have: In the class `Buch`, while calling the output function `ausgabe()` the extra information `autor` will be printed automatically. But for the remaining informations from `Medium` class, could you help. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: please simplify the classes and post the Medium.h file

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your code looks correct so far, but the parts you posted is not *Complete*.

Comment: and this: `personAusgeliehen.getName()` ? You havn't even mentioned. also change `switch (status)` simply with `if (status)`.

Comment: Where is your Medium class declaration ?

Comment: sorry im new to stack overflow:) basically the whole thing is about a "library" that contains books, magizines and DVDs. I left out the parts of DVD and magazin because they are basucally the same. The gol is to print the whole "library" and depending on the type of "Medium" different information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now depending on the type of Medium to be printed, I would like to add
>   extra information to be printed. E.g. if the Medium is a book,
>   information about author should be printed too.

So you are looking for dynamic-polymorphism. Then, you need to make `void ausgabe()const` function to `virtual` in your base class(`Medium`), in order to call it polymorphically. And you need to `override` it in other subclasses(for instance class `Buch`). In the given code anyways these are not there. In addition to that, you also need `virtual` destructor at your base class.

Then in your class `Buch`'s `ausgabe()` should be:

```
void ausgabe()const override
{
    Medium::ausgabe(); // call first base class's ausgabe()
    std::cout << "autor :" << autor << std::endl;
}
```

Then in your main, you can do this: [<kbd>**See an example code here**</kbd>](https://www.ideone.com/J49PQp)

```
int main ()
{
   std::unique_ptr<Medium> some_objects[2];
   some_objects[0] = std::make_unique<Medium>("Some Title");
   some_objects[1] = std::make_unique<Buch>("Title 2", "user9775960");

   for(auto& obj_type: some_objects)
      obj_type->ausgabe();
   return 0;
}
```

---

PS: always try to post English written code in the community, so that everybody can follow.

Comment: Thanks alot man! The **virtual** in front of **ausgabe** function in Base class Medium made it! The destructor in **medium** was virtual already i think. Thank you very much for your time and help!:)